# Infer probability of a specific value from kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x

let's say I have ths simple code that plot the kernel of some data. I would like to extract from this the probability given to a specific value let's say 2, which should be something like 0.145.
I know that statistically it is not very relevant but I need this to compute precisely the common area between two distributions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
data = [1.5]*7 + [2.5]*2 + [3.5]*2 + [4.5]*3 + [5.5]*1 + [6.5]*7
density = gaussian_kde(data)
xs = np.linspace(0,8,200)
plt.plot(xs,density(xs))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `evaluate()` method of the `gaussian_kde` object you create like so:

```
print(density.evaluate(2))
```

Output is:

```
>> [ 0.14731622]
```

See [this page in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.evaluate.html) for more details.